# What is MDAC and how we can use in our program

Tags: c#, com

What is MDAC and how we can use in our program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `MDAC` as a bunch of drivers, as a developer, you don't really need to know many details about it, just that it's installed. It used to be an issue to make sure that the right version was installed, but nowdays a recent version will be install on pretty much all Windows machines so you usually don't have to worry about it unless you're doing something advanced.

To use it just write some code to access one of the supported datasources. Look at `OleDbConnection` and related classes. More information about that class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28VS.71%29.aspx).